# typo3: how to change size of introduction package logo

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have changed the logo from the introduction package by uploading my logo in file admin and then set the constant page.logo.file = fileadmin/introduction/images/introduction-package.svg to refer my logo. This works fine. Question: how to change the size of the logo?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

- switch to the `Template`module in the left column
- select the root page in the site tree
- switch to the `Constant editor` above the main window
- select `Bootstrap package: Logo (7)` from the `Category` select box
- find the `Height` and `Width` fields and change the values by clicking on the pencil icon
- save you changes
- clear the cache

Now you have the new size in place.